# Is it possible to have the 2 line preview of a question properly formatted?

Tags: feature-request, questions, markdown-preview

When browsing through questions on SO, the 2 line preview is often helpful, especially with poorly worded titles. However, when these first 2 lines contain `code` or **bold** text or some other formatting, it makes the text difficult to read. Is it possible to maintain the formatting for those lines?

I know there are problems with line breaks, but comments work well with limited formatting capabilities. If that can also be used for the 2 line preview, it would be very helpful. However, if that slows servers down considerably or has other negative consequences, that would be nice to know. I do prefer function over form(atting).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're just inserting the text into a `<div>`, so it wouldn't be too hard to put some basic HTML/CSS in there also.  It'd sure be nice if they didn't all look like run-on sentences.

Comment: Surely some processing of the HTML needs to be done before inserting into the div, just to ensure tags are correctly closed off and random short snippets aren't going to fubar the rest of the page layout?

Comment: @slugster, yes, putting that basic stuff in there will take some processing, but they probably do it up front for every question, so it shouldn't be much of a hit.